# vuex store value in Mapstate undefined after mounting

Tags: vue.js, vuex

A vue component  is supposed to show cards:

```
<template>
<div class="custom-container" v-if="currentGame.id != undefined">
    <div class="text-center"  >
        
        <br>
        <br>

       
        curentGameId = {{ currentGame.id}}
         
        <h1> {{currentGame.naam}}</h1>
       
    
        
    <div  v-for="card in cards" v-bind:key="card.id">  
        <div class="card text-center card-bg mt-2"  >
           
            <div class="card-body mb-2" style="width: 100%"> 
                <h3> {{card.title}}   </h3>
                <p> {{card.description}}</p>
                <img class="img-circle" style="width:150px" v-bind:src="card.picture" alt="Card Image">
                <br>
                <button @click="deleteCard(card.id)" class="btn btn-danger m-1" style="width:100px;color:white">  Delete  </button>
                <button @click="editCard(card), showCardForm=true" class="btn btn-warning m-1" style="width:100px;color:black">  Edit  </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
</template>

import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {

   async  mounted(){

    await this.getCards((this.currentGame.id)),  
                      //WHEN I replace this.currentGame.id by e.g. 8 it works
        console.log('component mounted')
      
    },
      computed: {

    ...mapState([
        'cards', 'games' , 'currentGame' 
        ]),
    
    },
 methods: {

        ...mapActions([ 'getCards',  'getGames', 'addGame', 'fetchSpelerCards'  ]),
```

In actions.js I defined getCards() as follows:

```
export const getCards = async ({commit},game_id) => {
    await fetch(`api/cardsByGame/${game_id}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res=>{

       commit('SET_CARDS', res);
       console.log("cards ="+ + JSON.stringify(res));
    })
}
```

The component is placed in a parent template as

```
<ManageCards></ManageCards>
```

When I change the currentGame in the parent ( and also in the vuex store), the cards to be shown in the component do not change along.

The currentGame.name changes, but the cards arrays is not filled accordingly. It remains empty.

It looks like the getCards() function is only called once when the parent is loaded.
The currentGameId is undefined then..
After that it is not called again

When I change the currentGame in the parent (so also in the vuex store) and browse back and forth it adjusts the page correctly.

I tried using props, but that did not solve my problem.
Apparently I am missing something essential here...

Does anyone see what I am missing?

Comment: can you provide some minimal reproducible links for your problem?

Comment: project runs only local, I have no links... :(

Comment: Nilesh is asking if you can perhaps create a reproducible example using an online IDE such as codesandbox or jsfiddle that you can then share here and others can run and debug it

Comment: my initial thought is that you might need to think about using a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) in your component to run your `getCards()` function whenever `currentGame.id` changes.  even if `id` is initially null, it'll run as soon as `id` becomes something not null

Comment: I get currentGame form vuex using ...mapState as shown above.  Added   ` watch:{
       currentGame:
            { function(value){
                 this.getCards(value.id);
            }
       }
    }, `  This does not work. Am not sure how to watch the vuex state variable.  @yoduh

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out that the key to this problem is

```
key:
```

When I implement a key attribute to the component in the parent it is updated as soon as the vuex store value is updated:

In the parent template I have:

```
<ManageCards :key = "currentGame.id"></ManageCards>
```

In the parent script I get the currentGame.id from the vuex store using ...mapState:

```
 computed: {
        ...mapState([
        'games' , 'token','currentGame'
        ]),
```